# Help with Determinants

Tags: math, linear-algebra

[image]

Okay so i understand the first det, which is why i got the correct solution. However for the second det, im not sure how to solve it since because of the different coefficents (0,2,4) and i tried of different solutions. If anyone can give me a clear way to solve these it would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: this is a math, but not, as is, a signal processing question, and thus, off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the determinants along the middle column, we get for the first determinant:

$ -(bf-ec) + (af-cd)  -(ae-bd) = -3$ $\hspace{1cm}$ $ [1]$

And for the second determinant, we get

$-(bf-ec) + 2(af-cd)  -3(ae-bd) = -2 $ $\hspace{1cm}$ $ [2]$

The required determinant is

$  2(af-cd)  -4(ae-bd) $ $\hspace{1cm}$

Which is just $2*([2] - [1])$, which boils down to $2$.